# How do I force text messages to send and receive via iMessage?

Tags: ios, messages

When I chat with two of my friends (say A. and T.), our iPhones use text instead of iMessage. It used to work using iMessage, but one day, it switched to text. A, T and myself otherwise use iMessage with other contacts without any problem. It's only A <-> me and T <-> me which uses text.

How do I reset iMessage in order to re-enable it with these two friends?

Answer (score 8):

You can delete the SMS messages from the conversation and just leave the iMessages. Then reset your phone using the sleep/wake + home buttons.  This has restored the default to Send via imessage again for the conversation.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Edsel - this worked for me! Thank you so much for the advice :)

Comment: Don't need to reboot, just tap home button twice and swipe up on iMessage to kill it, then run it again.

Answer (score 7):

Try disabling iMessage in Settings → Messages → iMessage. Turn it off and then turn it back on. After doing this, close all apps and restart your phone by holding down the Lock button and the Home button for ten seconds. If this does not resolve the issue, it may related to the other users' devices.

You can also try restoring your iPhone though iTunes and setting up as a new device if you don't believe it's related to the other users.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Sprint and Google Voice, see this support article from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4091

Summary:

> Integrating your Sprint account with Google Voice may prevent your mobile phone number from being registered for use with FaceTime video calls and iMessage text messages.
>
> This occurs only when your Sprint phone number and Google Voice number are not the same. It should not affect your ability to send or receive SMS or MMS messages, or to receive or place FaceTime calls or iMessages using an email address instead of your phone number.

The support article doesn't give a solution, but I infer that you would need to change something with respect to Google Voice. I don't have a Sprint account and I don't know what it means to integrate a Sprint account with Google Voice.

Comment: Please summarize or excerpt the article in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone, so that it is still valuable if the link breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue (also with a person named "A") and was able to resolve it by sending an iMessage to A.'s email address, which she had registered to receive iMessages. She received it fine. That seemed to wake her iPhone up to the fact that I was sending from an iMessage-capable number, as she was then able to send me an iMessage to my mobile number, where just minutes before it didn't work.

We then repeated the procedure in reverse (she iMessage'd my email address). Now we are both able to send each other iMessages to each other's mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings`. This reset my iPhone back to iMessages when it got stuck in a rut sending text messages to another iPhone user.

Comment: Note that this will also affect your WiFi settings and you will lose all saved wifi passwords. (Also it didn't change anything about the text messages for me.)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 16:

- send the message normally (blue bubble)
- tap and hold on the blue bubble
- this menu shows up, select send as text
  [image]
- the bubble turns green

You will only see this option if your conversation is with a phone number. You can change this by tapping/holding the message icon of the contact and then selecting the number.